# Not receiving Firefox update notifications

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-automatic-updates

I am running as a standard user on Windows 7.

It seems unless I run as administrator I don't receive notifications that a new Firefox update is out, and thus no opportunity to update aside from doing so manually or logging in as Administrator.

Is there a way I can receive update notifications as a standard user?

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-installing Firefox in to the `C:\Users\..` directory.

That way I think the automatic update can run as UAC restrictions aren't as strict for the `C:\Users\` directory.